# Change Tracking generating enormous transaction logs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, change-tracking

I'm troubleshooting a 24GB DB that is generating approx 2GB (compressed) of transaction logs/60min.

Using the following command I'm tried to examine the contents of the log:

```
SELECT Operation, Context, AllocUnitName, [Lock Information], Description
FROM sys.fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
```

Most of the rows appear like this:

[image: Transaction logs]

I used this query to look at the contents on the syscommittab table which appears to be an index table for Change Tracking (enabled in this DB)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
GO
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM sys.dm_tran_commit_table
ORDER BY commit_time DESC
```

[image: syscommittab table]

This is where I get lost, I assume that based on the time stamps there are approx 3-4 changes per sec being made in Change Tracking which I would expect as its tracking every table in the DB. The operation is a `DELETE` which I assume is a cleanup task running.

Could there be another reason?

Is there any other method to determine why the log is so busy?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. In one case we had a 60GB log generated in less than 2 days.